# unable to send correct response in POST request with Node / Express

Tags: node.js, express

I am doing a POST request to an endpoint in Express.js, and I am unable to send back the proper data in the response:

```
router.post("/", upload.single("avatar"), jsonParser, async (req, res) => {
  const imageUrl = req.file.location;
  const userId = req.file.originalname;  
  try {
    const {
      result: { ok }
    } = await updateOne(
      users,
      { _id: mongo.ObjectID(userId) },
      { $set: { avatarUrl: imageUrl } }
    );
    if (ok === 1) {
      console.log("req.file.location", req.file.location);
      res.json({ url: req.file.location });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.warn("error updating avatarUrl", error);
  }
});
```

`req.file.location` is logging out correctly, but when I log out the response in the client, then I am getting `"type": "default", "status": 200, "ok": true, "headers"...` Why does the response not just give me the specified `{url: req.file.location}` that I am trying to return? Where does this other data even originate?

Comment: `var fileLocation= req.file.location` `res.json({ url: fileLocation });` try this

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the issue was that it's returning a promise.

I'm not sure how to resolve promise before sending response, but I have been able to handle promise on client side by doing:

```
    response.json().then(data => {
      // data.url
    });
```